# Problem with html tags in Struts2 while displaying

Tags: html, struts2

Hi
   I have data which includes HTML tags in database, am retriving below data from database and displaying the same in UI, but issue is am not getting  `CC6 Filament` text in bold, i had placed these 2 words in between  html   tag....

**Data from Database**:

```
  Incandescent Lamp, <b>CC6 Filament</b> 12 Standard Package, 150 Watt, 120 Volt, PAR38, 4-5/16 Inch, Medium Side Prong, 2000 Hour, Floodlight, For Compact Flood
```

Code used to display above text from database In JSP: *shortDesc="ABOUE MENTIONED TEXT"*

```
<p><s:property value="shortDesc" /></p>
```

Data is being displayed along with bold tag... in Struts2....

Thank you

Comment: try this: `<p><s:property value="shortDesc" escape="false" /></p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default property escapes HTML.  You need to do something like this:

```
<p><s:property value="shortDesc" escape="false" /></p>
```

More info here: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/Property.html

Comment: One's comment is other's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solved : I used **escapeHtml="false"** to overcome HTML tag escape

```
<s:property value="shortDesc" escapeHtml="false" />
```